# Should I ask a question about Script-Fu on Graphic Design?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

Should I ask a questin about *Script-Fu* on *Graphic Design*? If not, where are chances highest that I will have such a question answered, specifically about *Script-Fu's* API?

Comment: Well, the QA site's name is *Graphics Design* for a reason. Also, SO is very permissive on questions that would be better fit for other forums. Example: what if I had a Linux shell script running on Ubuntu that outputted TeX from maps on a DB that was meant for a web app? Unix.SE? AskUbuntu? TeX.SE? GIS.SE? DBA.SE? WebApps.SE? None of these, SO!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Script-Fu questions of any sort would be off-topic on GraphicDesign, just as Action Script, javascript or scripting in general would be.

*Any* API questions would be more at home on StackOverflow. They certainly wouldn't fit in GD (even assuming there's anyone here who would have an answer, which seems unlikely), nor Programming.SE, which from its FAQ is more concerned with meta-level discussions about programming in general.

Comment: Agreed!  Questions about how to use a Script-Fu plugin would probably be appropriate for SuperUser, but questions about the API definitely sound StackOverflow-y.